# Is there a script to change keyboard layout on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I need a little program to change the keyboard layout to `International US` and I need another program to change it back to `Portuguese` (ABNT2 or ABNT).

Is there any way to make a batch file or something like that to make the process faster?

Answer (score 3):

Why install another program, when Windows can do the work for you?

Press start. Type `Region and Language` and hit enter. Click on `Keyboards and Languages` and then `Change keyboards`. Click on the `add` button, and find your language of choice. There is no hard limit on how many keyboard layouts you can have at any one time, so go wild. Move the languages up and down depending on the order you want..

[image: This page has a lot of languages. Too many of them.]

When you click `apply`, you will now have an easy way to switch between the two keyboard layouts. It's right there in the right hand corner.

[image: Switching this will do magic.]

If you want to switch keyboard layout without clicking, simply press `left-alt+shift` and you will switch to the new language.

Comment: Seems like a combination of both your answer and my answer, with a bit more care and pruning, could become a community wiki page for easy reference in the future. What do you think?

Comment: I'm open for that

Answer (score 3):

If you set up multiple keyboard layouts in Windows, you can also configure a hotkey to easily switch between them using the language bar or with a hotkey.

Left Alt + Shift should be configured *by default* to switch back and forth between two configured keyboard layouts. You can also customize the hotkeys in the control panel under Regional & Language Settings: [image: keyboard layout hotkeys]